# WordPress Covert post ID in loop to array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

**Issue:**

Wanted to create an array using all `$post->ID` from all of my published articles. However in my WordPress, I have `$tokenID` which is the key to display certain article if matched to `$post->ID`.

**Code Fig. 1**

```
$tokenID = 244; 

$io_ID = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'sdm_downloads', 'posts_per_page' => -1] );
while ( $io_ID->have_posts() ) : $io_ID->the_post();

  print_r($post->ID);

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Result:** 255254253251244

*This is what the `$post->ID` when I echoed inside `while()` loop, where it should be 255, 254, 253, 251, 244*

I tried `str_split` and result almost near to what i wanted to achieve. Here's the output.

**Code Fig. 2**

```
$tokenID = 244; 

$io_ID = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'sdm_downloads', 'posts_per_page' => -1] );
while ( $io_ID->have_posts() ) : $io_ID->the_post();

  $arr2 = str_split($post->ID, 3);
  // print_r($arr2);

  if( in_array($tokenID, $arr2) ) {
    $set = 'true';
  } else {
    $set = 'false';
  }

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

echo $set;
```

**Result of print_r:** Array ( [0] => 255 ) Array ( [0] => 254 ) Array ( [0] => 253 ) Array ( [0] => 251 ) Array ( [0] => 244 )

**Result of condition:** "true"

*Even if the `$tokenID` is different, `$set` output still resulted to `true`.

**Question**

How can I achieve to create a conditional arrangement of my `$post->ID` while it was converted to array? I want to look and match first the `$tokenID` and `$post->ID` if the value is exist before I post the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe help for this solution!

```
$tokenID = 244; 
$all_posts = get_posts('post_type=sdm_downloads');
$all_id = array();
foreach( $all_posts as $all_post ) {
$all_id[] = $all_post->ID;
}
//$arr2 = str_split($all_titles, 3);
if( in_array($tokenID, $all_id) ) {
    $set = 'true';
  } else {
    $set = 'false';
  }
echo $set;
```